How do we know for sure that the dedekind axiom is logically independent of the other axioms?
I am reading Topological Spaces: From Distance to Neighborhood by Buskes und Rooij. They present $\mathbb{R}$ as a mathematical object satisfying the following axioms.

It is a field.

The elements of the field has an order structure compatible with the field structure

There is a submonoid  called natural numbers $ \mathbb{N}$ having the multiplicative identity and further property that if there is a subset X of it having the property that, if $ x \in X $ then so is $x+1$, then $ \mathbb{N} \subset X$ with $ 1 \in X$

Archimedian property holds

The dedekind axiom holds



Dedekind Axiom. Let $A,B$ be non empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose union is $\mathbb{R}$, a for every $a \in A$ and $ b \in B$, $a<b$, then there is number $c$ for which $A = (-\infty,c), B = [c,\infty)$ or $A=(-\infty,c]$, $B=(c,\infty)$

How can we know for sure that the dedekind axiom is logically independent of all the other axioms? If one challenges themself to write sets which satisfies the internal assumption of the dedekind axioms, then we can only write set which it implies. It seems quite obvious to me.

"If one challenges themself to write sets which satisfies the internal assumption of the dedekind axioms, then we can only write set which it implies. It seems quite obvious to me." I'm not sure I understand. To show it is independent we wouldn't write sets to satisfy it.  We'd write sets that don't satisfy it.  Such as the classic counter example $\mathbb Q$.

Natural numbers aren’t a ring, though.

As written, axiom 3 seems incorrect to me. Did you forget to require $0 \in X$ or something on that line? Otherwise, what prevents us to take $X = \emptyset$ and obtain $\mathbb N \subset X$?

The field $\Bbb Q$ satisfies the first four axioms, but not the Dedekind axiom. In fact, if, for instance, $A=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\leqslant0\vee x^2<2\}$ and $B=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x>0\wedge x^2>2\}$, then:

$A,B\ne\emptyset$;
$A\cup B=\Bbb Q$.
for each $a\in A$ and each $b\in B$, $a<b$,

but there is no $c\in\Bbb Q$ such that $A=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x<c\}$ and $B=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\geqslant c\}$ or that $A=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x\leqslant c\}$ and $B=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x>c\}$.
Therefore, it is impossible to deduce the Dedekind axiom from the other four. And the example of $\Bbb R$ shows that it is impossible to deduce the negation of the Dedekind axiom from  the other four. So, it is an independent axiom.

Why does Q not satisfy the dedwkind axioms

Just take $A=(-\infty,\pi)\cap\Bbb Q$ and $B=(\pi,\infty)\cap\Bbb Q$, for instance.

The perfect one word sentence answer!  To expand on the comment, the dedekind axiom basically says for every "cutting partition" one of sets must have a minimal or maximal element.  If $A=$ all the rationals less than $\pi$ and $B=$ all the rationals more than $\pi$ that is clearly a cutting partition (the union is all rationals not equal to $\pi$ which is all rationals; and every rational larger than $\pi$ is larger than any rational less than $\pi$). So DA would say either there is a largest rational less than $\pi$ (there isn't) or there is a smallest rational more than $\pi$ (there isn't).

Using $\pi$ as an example is awkward, since it requires reasoning "outside the field" to define. An alternative is for example $A = {x \in \mathbb Q : x<0 \lor x^2 < 2}$ and $B = {x \in \mathbb Q : x > 0 \land x^2 > 2}$, which are defined "internally" and rely on $x^2 = 2$ not having a solution over $\mathbb Q$.

@MishaLavrov Indeed. Would you mind if I edit my answer and add to it that example?

Is the union to that really Q @MishaLavrov

@JoséCarlosSantos I don't mind in the least!

@CatharticEncephalopathy It's always possible I've made a mistake, of course, but the intent of that definition is to describe (algebraically over $\mathbb Q$) the sets $A = (-\infty,\sqrt2) \cap \mathbb Q$ and $B = (\sqrt2, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q$.

@MishaLavrov Thank you. It's done.

Is it possible to prove that the union is $Q$ without going into the real numebrs?

@CatharticEncephalopathy Sure.

But how do you prove it then? @José

Take $q\in\Bbb Q$. If $q\leqslant0$, then $q\in A$. Otherwise, you know that $q^2\ne2$, and so $q^2<2$ or $q^2>2$. If $q^2<2$, then $q\in A$; otherwise, $q\in B$.
